# How to wrap and unwrap selected text in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, rangy

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/73YXM/)

JsFiddle Demo completely work for wrap text but i'm not know how it is unwrap selected text.

```
 range.text = '[' + tag + ']' + selectedText + '[/' + tag + ']';
```

how is it unwrap tag and get original selected text.

Comment: This is confusing, because in your jsfiddle, you aren't adding tags, you are adding text.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will save you much trouble here:

[jQuery wrap docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

[jQuery unwrap() docs](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

$('findyourtaghere').contents().unwrap();

Comment: This will only work if your text is actually wrapped in a tag, your jsfiddle is actually just adding new text.

Comment: But It could be not working here!. I want to remove special character when second time replace text.http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use something like this:

```
var element = document.createElement('span');
element.originalText = selectedText;
element.textContent = '[' + tag + ']' + selectedText + '[/' + tag + ']';
element.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(this.originalText), this);  
};
range.insertNode(element);
```

I used `span` element here, not textNode, it's easy to use for your purposes. But you need to take care of browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found what I was looking for, but I found the solution for what you're looking for, this single line will take the parent element of the selected text and remove it keeping the text where it is, unless you select something other than text like an element for example, but then it would be another problem.

```
$(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement).unwrap();
```